# Index Function using joins

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, indexing

How would I go about creating a function-index to increase the performance of this statement?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM TableName as a, TableName as b
WHERE a.first_name = b.first_name 
  AND a.last_name = b.last_name 
  AND a.person_id < b.person_id;
```

Comment: Interesting:  You have tagged this Oracle, but Oracle doesn't allow `as` for a table alias.

Comment: I did not know that, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, learn explicit `join` syntax:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TableName a JOIN 
     TableName b
     ON a.first_name = b.first_name AND a.last_name = b.last_name AND
        a.person_id < b.person_id;
```

The index that is best for this query:

```
create index idx_tablename_first_last_person on tablename(first_name, last_name, person_id);
```

You can actually swap the first two columns in the index, but `person_id` needs to be third because of the inequality.

Comment: Is there any reason why the inequality needs to be the third column? And what implications would this have on the performance? It looks as though it wouldn't hold any benefit

Comment: @Josh123 . . . The index is a covering index for the query, so the original data pages never need to be read.  As for how composite indexes work, I think the MySQL documentation does  a pretty good job explaining them (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).  The basics of index usage are common across databases although Oracle does have some more sophisticated algorithms to take advantage of indexes.